# KStream aggregate with custom value type and known state store

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to perform an aggregation on a stream with key of type String and value of custom type - as follows

```java
stream.groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(),barSerde))
      .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
      .aggregate(Foo::new,
                 (String key, Bar bar, Foo foo) -> {
                   foo.updateMap(bar.getKey(), bar.getValue());
                   return foo;
                 }, 
                 Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), fooSerde));
```

I was able to get the required results until I started specifying the state store in `Materialized` function as follows

```java
stream.groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(),barSerde))
      .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
      .aggregate(Foo::new,
                 (String key, Bar bar, Foo foo) -> {
                   foo.updateMap(bar.getKey(), bar.getValue());
                   return foo;
                 }, 
                 Materialized.<String, Foo, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(storeTopic))
                   .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                   .withValueSerde(fooSerde));
```

I get a compile error

```
Error:(122, 17) java: no suitable method found for aggregate(Foo::new,(key,daBea[...]an; },org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized<java.lang.String,com.test.bean.Foo,org.apache.kafka.streams.state.KeyValueStore<org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes,byte[]>>)
method org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindowedKStream.<VR>aggregate(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Initializer<VR>,org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Aggregator<? super java.lang.String,? super com.test.bean.Bar,VR>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) VR
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
method org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindowedKStream.<VR>aggregate(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Initializer<VR>,org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Aggregator<? super java.lang.String,? super com.test.bean.Bar,VR>,org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized<java.lang.String,VR,org.apache.kafka.streams.state.WindowStore<org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes,byte[]>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) VR
    (argument mismatch; org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized<java.lang.String,com.test.bean.Foo,org.apache.kafka.streams.state.KeyValueStore<org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes,byte[]>> cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized<java.lang.String,VR,org.apache.kafka.streams.state.WindowStore<org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes,byte[]>>))
```

How do I specify both the Serdes and the stateStore topic with `Materialized`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are doing a windowed aggregation, the expected store type is not `KeyValueStore` but `WindowStore`.